# Выбор двух столбцов из разных таблиц SQLiteDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Есть две таблицы первая называется user в ней столбцы id, name и другая таблица info в ней столбцы key, range, owner_id

Как я могу получить значения в SQLiteDataAdapter, если с первой таблицы мне нужно взять name а со второй range, при этом range брать на основании owner_id который должен быть равен id из таблицы info, при этом нужно взять значение которые соответствуют key = 'last'

Comment: Используйте join в sql запросе

Comment: @tym32167, уже пробую)

Answer (score 1):

sql запрос будет примерно таким:

```
SELECT user.name, info.range
FROM user
INNER JOIN info on info.owner_id= user.id
where info.key = 'last'
```

я его не проверял, возможности нет, но это то, что вы ищите (Inner Join)

С уважением и удачи.